# Sort Value in Mongodb

Tags: sorting, mongodb

I'm writing PHP application with Mongodb. I can search like

```
$regex='/.*sim.*/i'; 
$find['Word']=new mongoRegex($regex); 
$cursor = $collection->find($find);
```

and got result like this

> assimilate
>
> facsimile
>
> fortissimo
>
> generalissimo
>
> passim
>
> persimmon
>
> persimmons
>
> similar
>
> similarly
>
> simple
>
> simple hurt
>
> simpler
>
> simplest
>
> simply

But I want to sort like

```
1. sim 
2. sim* 
3. *sim* 
4. sim*
```

How to wrote regular expression or how to sort like this ? In MySQL, I wrote

```
SELECT * , IF( `Word` = 'sim', 1, IF( `Word` LIKE 'sim%', 2, IF( `Word` LIKE '%sim', 4, 3 ) ) ) AS `sort` FROM `dblist` WHERE `Word` LIKE '%sim%' ORDER BY `sort` , `Word`
```

Now, I'm planning to change MySQL to Mongodb but problem is searching result. I can't sort result like MySQL in mongodb.

Update:

I can sort after fetch the data but the problem is paging. The result will come over 1000 per times. I don't want to fetch all result from database. So, sort in database and fetch the result with paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to do that kind of sorting in your own code after fetching the result. I'm not aware of any equivalent to SQL's `AS`.

Comment: Yes, to do custom (function based) sorting you would have to do it in the client.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb collection has [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.sort.php) operation, if you want more complex operations, do it on client side.